# Crear la clave key propia para sort()

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordenamiento, knn

Me gustaría ordenar los puntos etiquetados del más cercano al más lejano para hacer mi proprio knn:

```
def knn_classify(k, labeled_points, new_point):
  """chaque point labelisé devrait être une paire (point, label)"""

  # ordonne les points labelisés du plus proche au plus lointain
  by_distance = sorted(labeled_points, key= lambda (point, _): distance(point, new_point))
  
  # trouve les labels pour les k les plus proches
  k_nearest_labels = [label for _, label in by_distance[:k]]

  # et les faire voter
  return majority_vote(k_nearest_labels)
```

Sin embargo tengo problema con esto:

```
by_distance = sorted(labeled_points, key= lambda (point, _): distance(point, new_point))
```

En efecto me dice que:

```
by_distance = sorted(labeled_points, key = lambda (point, _): distance(point, new_point))
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: ¿Por qué pones dos parámetros en la lambda? Realmente sólo recibirá uno (cada elemento de la lista `labeled_points`)

Answer (score 1):

Las funciones lambda, a diferencia de las funciones normales, no aceptan en su sintaxis que los argumentos estén entre paréntesis.

La forma correcta de crear tu función lambda teniendo esto en cuenta sería:

```
lambda point, _: distance(point, new_point)
```